# Tentacles Curve Wave Effect

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves

[image: Curve Ripple Animation]

Anyone have any ideas on how to animate curves to perform like a wave effect instead of this side to side animation I did?

Took me a while to find an example but found one by [James Curran](https://dribbble.com/shots/4259292-Jelly):
[image: https://dribbble.com/shots/4259292-Jelly]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the wave modifier and press play animation.

In my example I rotated my object by 90 degrees without applying the rotation, so to have the desired effect.

Make sure to have enough geometry in your mesh, with evenly distribuited quads.

[image]

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

You could create your tentacle object, create a curve along the tentacle, give your tentacle a *Curve* modifier with the curve as *Object*, hook the curve's vertices to the bones of an armature, then move the bones to make the tentacle wave.

[image]